# Low Memory Index List in Python

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have the following code:

```
l = []
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(B):
        if predicate(i,j): 
            l.append((i, j))
```

Let's presume `A` and `B` are *very* *very* large numbers [~10e7], so `l` could be potentially of the immense size of `A * B` in the worse case. Presume that the function `predicate` to be a general function that decides whether to take or not to take the tuple `(i,j)`.

I'd like a solution that:

1. Reduces the amount of memory needed to save `l`
2. Allows for **efficient** random dereferencing of elements in `l`, i.e: We pick a random index `k` in `range(len(l))` and return `l[k]` **quickly**.
3. Builds the list `l` rather quickly (maybe `append` is not the right function to use?)

I'm just nothing that it is clear that (1), (2) and (3) may clash, and perhaps a python `list` is not the right way to go. Can anyone offer a different method?

Thank you !!

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: To go into more detail, what do you want to do with predicate? There may be a faster solution that iterating through two list.

Comment: For a random pair, how likely is the predicate true?

Comment: I think faster logic based on the predicate is possible, but for now I rather it be kept obscure, seeing we have many possible predicate functions

Comment: How "*very very* large" are the numbers?

Comment: @HeapOverflow:
1. About A*B/100000 of the inputs are taken on average.
2. Take A,B upwards of 10,000,000

Comment: @HeapOverflow - I'd happily go over the original need that created this problem, but the nice moderators here on Stack Overflow usually flag questions like that as "Needing more focus". I think the problem is currently well-defined, without getting into the nitty gritty of the overall problem.

Comment: @Mano I guess it's decent as is, but you might get more and better answers if you provided the real problem. I'm probably not the only one reluctant to spend time on this when it might just turn out later that the real problem allows something much better so that our earlier efforts were a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tuples and repeated `i`, you could mainly just store the `j`-values:

```
l = []
prefixsum = [0]
for i in range(A):
    J = [j for j in range(B) if predicate(i,j)]
    l.append(J)
    prefixsum.append(prefixsum[-1]) + len(J))
```

Then for a given `k`, binary search it in `prefixsum` to get `i` and then look up the `j` in the list.

Furthermore, instead of the lists of `int` objects you could also use Python [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) of 4-byte ints (or 3-byte ints with some extra work). NumPy arrays, which might also make the whole computation faster.

A rough test, ignoring some overheads, on a 64-bit Python:

```
# A list of 100 tuples takes 888 bytes (just the list object)
> l = [(10**6, 10**6 + j) for j in range(100)]
> l = [(10**l.__sizeof__()
888

# The tuples take 4000 bytes
> l = [(10**sum(t.__sizeof__() for t in l)
4000

# The i-value takes 28 bytes
> l[0][0].__sizeof__()
28

# The j-values take 2800 bytes
sum(j.__sizeof__() for _, j in l)
2800
```

So that's 7716 bytes for a list of 100 tuples of 2 ints. Now an `array` of the `j`-values:

```
> a = array.array('I', (j for i, j in l))
> a = array.a.__sizeof__()
472
```

That's 16 times less memory.